# Not picking up my plugin: Cannot read property 'text2Speech' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

```
(function($){
   $.fn.myLib = function (global) {

     global.text2Speech = {
       getSpeaker: function (lang, maxWordsPerPhrase) {
         var spkr = Object.create(speaker);
         spkr.lang = lang || 'en';
         // TODO: do a proper checking
         // this won't prevent a non number to be assigned here
         if (maxWordsPerPhrase) {
           spkr.maxWordsPerPhrase = maxWordsPerPhrase;
         }
         if (!sayIt) {
           createSayIt();
         }

         return speaker;
       }
     };
   }
 }(jQuery));


 $(function() {

      var t2s = window.myLib.text2Speech;
      // console.log(t2s);
      var spkr = t2s.getSpeaker('en', 16);

  });
```

I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text2Speech' of undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to name that variable something other than `global`?

Comment: Why are you trying to work off the window? Your jquery plugin should call jQuery().text2Speech()

Comment: Still no joy http://jsfiddle.net/ncnjy9c3/2/